# Why the same webpage have different font size when save as PDF in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, font-size

I'm using the fauture `save as pdf` in printing dialog of Google Chrome to print [this website](http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Sets.html). The website has two display options: 1. non-expand and 2. expand. In the 2nd option, the solution to exercise will be shown. The 1st option is by default when we visit the website, whereas to active the 2nd option, we need to click on the plus symbol on the top right corner:

[image]

I could not understand why the font size of PDF document is significantly smaller in the 2nd option.

- 1st option:

[image]

- 2nd option:

[image]

I save both of them as complete webpage and they have the same files, except for the `.html` file.

[image]

Could you please elaborate on how this problem arises and how to adjust the html file of the 2nd option to have the bigger font size as the 1st option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out: this is because the font size will be reduced so that long equation can fit in.